# How to save contact detail collected in flutter to native address book

Tags: flutter, contacts, flutter-dependencies

I am working on a simple project which is help to save your contact number.So my question is that how can i implicit my data in contact application and jump into contact application using flutter.I hope you understand what am i saying.

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 2):

I could see 2 plugins in [pub.dev](https://pub.deb) that can do this for you in Android and iOS.

1. [flutter_contact](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_contact) - A Flutter plugin to retrieve, create and save contacts and contact-related events on Android and iOS devices.
2. [contacts_service](https://pub.dev/packages/contacts_service) - A Flutter plugin to retrieve and manage contacts on Android and iOS devices.

Please have a look into them.

PS: Also checkout [flutter_simple_permissions](https://github.com/AppleEducate/flutter_simple_permissions) for asking user for appropriate permissions